# latin abbreviation for "one and the same"?

Tags: abbreviations

I want to say "...as compared to paracetamol (i.e., Aspirin)"

I think this is fine, but is there a latin abbreviation that literally means "one and the same"?

Comment: _As compared to_ doesn't mean _one and the same_, and aspirin is not the same drug as paracetamol.

Comment: Why do you want a Latin abbreviation? Especially one that you are not familiar with and therefore your readers will probably not be familiar with, either.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of how you want to use this because your example fragment doesn't really make sense by itself (and appears to be factually wrong).

Answer (score 1):

### Identical to

> Paracetamol is identical to acetaminophen.
>
> Aspirin is identical to acetylsalicylic acid.

### If you are desperate for Latin: id est, almost always abbreviated "i.e."

> She overdosed on paracetamol (i.e. acetaminophen).
>
> Aspirin (i.e. acetylsalicylic acid) is a remarkable antiplatelet, antipyretic and analgesic agent.